# reCaptcha on iPhone App using SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, recaptcha

Has anyone used reCaptcha on their iPhone application?  I am trying to figure out how to embed it in my App...

Comment: I want to do this because for example someone who signs up on the iPhone to my website, they are human but what if a hacker uses the http protocol sign up string and spams my website?  I guess a work around is to know the request is coming from an iphone.  How do you check for that?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to use reCaptcha in an iPhone app is by rendering a WebView within the app. There is a nice alternative to reCaptcha called kaptcha that actually has a usable api. http://code.google.com/p/kaptcha/

Comment: is it possible to resize the reCaptcha, rendering in a WebView. For small screen its too big and not responsive.

Answer (score -1):

use this http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/05/05/Add-text-to-image-%28UIImage%29.aspx find a nice background image for you app, and just randomly generate some number and/or text. not exactly a captcha, but it can work out. Hope it helps!