# How to impliment captcha varification in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, captcha

I have a task to work with captcha in my application which gives the same process of verification in my mobile application like website captcha process.

My question is to develop or integrate captcha in my application. and my hole code is developed in native iphone language. I have search a lot for integration of captcha in mobile application. But i haven't find any reference.

So please help me for this to develop captcha in my application without using webview.And provide some code or sample for it.

Comment: Have you noticed that none of the apps on the App Store have CAPTCHAs either? Ever wonder why?

Comment: I have seen captcha in 1 app in itune. Please search DealTiem.ie Mobile in lifestyle. and download that it is free. in that send mail section contains captcha code.

Comment: captcha is used for to find out whether the user is human or machine .in iphone u dont worry about it.because iphone sandbox wont allow other application to access other app.and more over apple will reject app if u send email as hiddenly.so no need of captcha here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reCaptcha on iPhone App using SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447470/recaptcha-on-iphone-app-using-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this 
http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/05/05/Add-text-to-image-%28UIImage%29.aspx 
find a nice background image for you app, and just randomly generate some number and/or text.
not exactly a captcha, but it can work out.
Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply Andrews.

I have already implement same like that. and it is working as captcha.

Comment: The link is expired please modify your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no Need to add Captcha in some Application, as Applications are not as like Web, So, as per my thinking there is no Need to attach the Captcha in some Application to prevent the Bots, Still if you need to embed it...
Yes, Here is the Possible way, Please check the following codes:

Take these outlets and variables:

```
NSArray *arrCapElements;
IBOutlet UILabel *Captcha_label;
IBOutlet UITextField *Captcha_field;
IBOutlet UILabel *Status_label;
```

and `IBActions` as:

```
- (IBAction)Reload_Action:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)Submit_Action:(id)sender;
```

In storyboard choose the font name as ***Chalkduster 30.0*** for the `Captcha_label`.

Now assign `arrCapElements` in `viewDidLoad()` as

```
arrCapElements = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i",@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"o",@"p",@"q",@"r",@"s",@"t",@"u",@"v",@"w",@"x",@"y",@"z",@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z", nil];
```

Code for load the Captcha:

```
-(void)load_captcha{
    @try {
        CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );  //  0.0 to 1.0
        CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from white
        CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from black
        Captcha_label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
        //Captcha_label.textColor=[UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
        NSUInteger elmt1,elmt2,elmt3,elmt4,elmt5,elmt6;
        elmt1 = arc4random() % [arrCapElements count];
        elmt2= arc4random() % [arrCapElements count];
        elmt3 = arc4random() % [arrCapElements count];
        elmt4 = arc4random() % [arrCapElements count];
        elmt5 = arc4random() % [arrCapElements count];
        elmt6 = arc4random() % [arrCapElements count];

        NSString *Captcha_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@",arrCapElements[elmt1-1],arrCapElements[elmt2-1],arrCapElements[elmt3-1],arrCapElements[elmt4-1],arrCapElements[elmt5-1],arrCapElements[elmt6-1]];
        //NSLog(@" Captcha String : %@",Captcha_string);
        Captcha_label.text = Captcha_string;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@",exception);
    }
}
```

Reload Action:

```
- (IBAction)Reload_Action:(id)sender {

    [self load_captcha];
}
```

Check the captcha Correct or not:

```
- (IBAction)Submit_Action:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"%@ = %@",Captcha_label.text,Captcha_field.text);
    if([Captcha_label.text isEqualToString: Captcha_field.text]){
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        Status_label.text =@"Success";
        Status_label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }else{
        Status_label.text =@"Faild";
        Status_label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

It will be shown like this:

[image: Demo Screen]

Help taken from: [Captcha Generator for iOS](https://ktrkathir.wordpress.com/2014/12/27/captcha-generator-for-ios/comment-page-1/)