# Certificate-based authentication on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, digital-certificate, client-certificates

I'm writing a J2SE client for my Google App Engine application which communicates with GAE via REST. I'm using Restlet for the REST handling. The client is running on a remote server.

Now i have doubts about the Authentication implementation; OAUTH2 seems not a good choice because there's no user available on the remote server side for the OAUTH2 challenge. The book Restlet In Action mentions **Certificate-based authentication**. This solution needs a trust store on the server.

**Is Certificate-based authentication possible on Google App Engine**? The trust store is already available for SSL communication, but is it also possible to use it for Certificate-based authentication

Comment: Authentication using Service Accounts would be ideal in your situation but the documentation seems to only cover this for clients accessing Google APIs. However, the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890175 seem to provide a solution for doing this in your own REST endpoints.